# Instagram Image Filters on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How does one go about adding image filters in an iPhone application? (similar to what Instagram and picplz have)

Comment: Take a look Brad Larson's [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). That is what you are looking for. Goodluck

Answer (score 44):

Folks,

I have made an attempt at replicating instagram and photoshop filters using pure CoreGraphics and direct pixel manipulation, not using OpenGL.

Find this project at:

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

** UPDATE **

You also should consider this project:
https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController

Comment: Well done @esilver. Good work. You should provide some example filters like Brannan, XPro2, etc. from the actual Instagram filter list.

Comment: @esilver yes your attempt helps me a lot also.But the app is getting crash for some  images in polaroidish image filter.Can you please tell how to solve that.

Comment: @esilver Can I use ios-image-filters project in my app or is it copyrighted?

Comment: It is MIT licensed. You may use in your app. Note that there are numerous other, better, and newer projects that do this sort of thing now, including libraries provided natively by iOS.

Comment: i use DLCImagePickerController but i am unable to integrate GPUImage. Please can you suggest me steps.

Answer (score 21):

Have you checked [simple-iphone-image-processing](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/)? It is a “simple C++ class with an Objective-C wrapper that provides a set of common image processing tasks” as well as `UIImage` conversion. It provides:

- [Canny edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detection)
- [Histogram equalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalisation)
- [Skeletonisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton)
- [Thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)), adaptive and global
- [Gaussian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) (used as a preprocessing step for canny edge detection)
- [Brightness normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing))
- [Connected region extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_extraction)
- Resizing – using interpolation

Other C++ open source libraries are:

1. http://cimg.sourceforge.net/
2. http://filters.sourceforge.net/

**Edit**
Also, take a look at this open-source code - https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no CoreImage library in the iOS SDK so you have to use OpenGLES to do image processing, Apple have an example application that demonstrates several techniques.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you can also port, most of the C code, from free image processing libraries. And then use pixel based modifications.

Comment: In this link you can see how to add C++ code in Objective-C: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1   So you just need to find the image processing c++ code of your desired instagram effect