# How to give a sepia effect to an image in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I am working on a app in which I have to give the following effects to image:

1. Auto Fix
2. Sepia

How can I give these effects to the image?
Is there any API in Objective C in which image can be filtered in multiple forms?

**I found answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928862/instagram-image-filters-on-iphone?answertab=votes#tab-top) I found the accurate answer.**

This is a very useful code if you are working on the filtration of the images in iPhone app.

Answer (score 3):

Add the category [UIImage+Filtering.h](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesUtilities/tree/master/Categories) to your code and type:

```
 UIImage* sepia = [myImage sepia];
```

I don't know what Auto Fix is. Is that brightness equalization? even out tones?

Answer (score 0):

For the sepia portion, you can composite your image using a blend mode of kCGBlendModeColor (see CGContextSetBlendMode() to apply the mode before drawing). Within your context, draw the image, then set the blend mode, then fill the image area with sepia colour. The image grey levels will be preserved, but colour and saturation will be taken from your sepia fill.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can u please provide me some code as I never worked on giving effects to image?