# How would I add a sepia effect to a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that I'm having problems adding a sepia effect to. Does anyone have any ideas or links that may be helpful, greatly appreciated!

Seb

Comment: There's a similar quest with answers and code examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549396/image-processing-glamour-filter-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the links pointed out or include Silverber's excellent [**Image Filters**](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters).

Also check this - [Instagram Image Filters on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928862/instagram-image-filters-on-iphone)